# How to know what terms will appear after partial fraction decomposition without actually calculating

Tags: calculus

[image]

I understand why they will appear after calculation except 6. I know that Ax^4 would appear since the difference between the largest power of numerator and denominator is 4. But why 2?

Comment: There is indeed a $4$ degree polynomial that will appear so a $x^2$ can appear too. So you probably have to show that the coefficient in front of $x^2$ is non-zero (or if $A_1$ can be $0$its trivially true).

Answer (score 1):

Partial fraction decomposition:

> Let $f$ and $g\neq 0$ be polynomials.
> Write $g$ as $g=c g_1^{n_1}\cdots g_m^{n_m}$,
> where each $g_i$ is irreducible.
> Then there exist unique polynomials $p,f_{1,1},\dots,f_{m,n_m}$ such that
> $$
> \frac{f}{g}=p+\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{f_{i,j}}{g_i^{j}}
> $$
> where $\deg f_{i,j}<\deg g_i$ and $\deg p = \deg f - \deg g$ (if negative, then $p=0$).

In the exercise,
it seems that each $\frac{f_{i,j}}{g_i^j}$ is considered a single term,
but $p$ is not considered a single term.
Instead, each monomial in $p$ is considered a single term.
When asked whether a term of a given type exists in the decomposition,
we then know that each monomial in $p$ must exist in the decomposition.
In your case, $\deg p=4$,
so $A_1 x^2$ is indeed a monomial in $p$,
and it exists in the decomposition.